# Software solution to use one set of speaker for multiple sound-output devices

Tags: windows-7, osx-lion, audio, network-shares, kodi

In the room I'm currently working in, I have a:

- Primary computer, running Windows 7 - connected to speakers,
- Secondary MacBook, running OS X Lion,
- "TV-computer" running Linux/XBMC or similar..

..which are all connected through my wireless/wired home-network.

Which works great, my problem, however, is that I only have one pair of speakers (5.1). 
I'm looking for a software that can make my primary computer act as a **"sound-switch"** over my network. A software that makes me able to select from which sound-output the speakers should play from, preferably from all devices.

I hope you understood what I meant. Any help is truly appreciated.

*EDIT: Like Steve said, the use of a mixer would probably be preferred, but this is what I am trying to avoid.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some heavy Google usage, I found what I needed: [AirFoil](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/). It's working simple and awesome, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a software solution, but is in some ways simpler. I use a hardware mixer called [pMix](https://www.americanrecorder.com/products/pmix-personal-audio-mixer)

I got mine for about $35 (the link shows $80 list price). You can use any one or all three of the inputs by adjusting the individual audio level knobs.

Comment: I do realize the usage of a mixer would be convenient, but I can't see why a software solution wouldn't be possible. Maybe it's time for me to write my own solution if there isn't any already, pretty simple logic, really. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've never looked for a software solution. I like the immediate access of hardware knobs. Good luck - I'll be intereseted to see if there is a software solution.